# Scraping image hrefs from an Ordered List using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to retrieve the images from this website (with permission).  Here is my code below with the website I want to access:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.vgmuseum.com/nes.htm"

page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html5lib")
li = soup.select('ol > li > a')
for link in li:
   print(link.get('href'))
```

The images I would like to use are in this ordered list here:
[list location for images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1w6aC.png)

Comment: You'd first have to scrape the left frame (`http://www.vgmuseum.com/nes_b.html`) to get a list of the URLs that correspond to each set of images you want, then you'd need to go to those URLs and scrape the images, so it's a multi-step process. I'm not going to write it for you since you have a good start, but that's how you'd approach it.

Comment: I'm not asking anyone to write code for me.  I'm just asking what needs to be improved. This is my first time using this library. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

The page you are working with consists of `iframe`s which is basically a way of including one page into the other. Browsers understand how `iframe`s work and would download pages and display them in the browser window.

*`urllib2`, though, is not a browser* and cannot do that. You need to explore where the list of links is located, in which `iframe` and then follow the url where this `iframe`'s content is coming from. In your case, the list of links on the left is coming from the `http://www.vgmuseum.com/nes_b.html` page.

Here is a working solution to follow links in the list of links, download pages containing images and the [downloading images](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16694907/771848) into the `images/` directory. I am using `requests` module and utilizing `lxml` parser teamed up with `BeautifulSoup` for faster HTML parsing:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin

import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.vgmuseum.com/nes_b.html"


def download_image(session, url):
    print(url)
    local_filename = os.path.join("images", url.split('/')[-1])

    r = session.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            if chunk:  # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)


with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'
    }
    response = session.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

    for link in soup.select('ol > li > a[href*=images]'):
        response = session.get(urljoin(response.url, link.get('href')))
        for image in BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml").select("img[src]"):
            download_image(session, url=urljoin(response.url, image["src"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the url in @Dan's comment above for parsing.

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.vgmuseum.com/nes_b.html'

page = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
li = soup.find('ol')
soup = BeautifulSoup(str(li), 'html.parser')
a = soup.find_all('a')
for link in a:
    if not link.get('href') == '#top' and not link.get('href') == None:
        print(link.get('href'))
```

Output:

```
images/nes/10yard.html
images/nes2/10.html
pics2/100man.html
images/nes/1942.html
images/nes2/1942.html
images/nes/1943.html
images/nes2/1943.html
pics7/1944.html
images/nes/1999.html
images/nes2/2600.html
images/nes2/3dbattles.html
images/nes2/3dblock.html
images/nes2/3in1.html
images/nes/4cardgames.html
pics2/4.html
images/nes/4wheeldrivebattle.html
images/nes/634.html
images/nes/720NES.html
images/nes/8eyes.html
images/nes2/8eyes.html
images/nes2/8eyesp.html
pics2/89.html
images/nes/01/blob.html
pics5/boy.html
images/03/a.html
images/03/aa.html
images/nes/abadox.html
images/03/abadoxf.html
images/03/abadoxj.html
images/03/abadoxp.html
images/03/abarenbou.html
images/03/aces.html
images/03/action52.html
images/03/actionin.html
images/03/adddragons.html
images/03/addheroes.html
images/03/addhillsfar.html
images/03/addpool.html
pics/addamsfamily.html
pics/addamsfamilypugsley.html
images/nes/01/adventureislandNES.html
images/nes/adventureisland2.html
images/nes/advisland3.html
pics/adventureisland4.html
images/03/ai4.html
images/nes/magickingdom.html
pics/bayou.html
images/03/bayou.html
images/03/captain.html
images/nes/adventuresofdinoriki.html
images/03/ice.html
images/nes/01/lolo1.html
images/03/lolo.html
images/nes/01/adventuresoflolo2.html
images/03/lolo2.html
images/nes/adventuresoflolo3.html
pics/radgravity.html
images/03/rad.html
images/nes/01/rockyandbullwinkle.html
images/nes/01/tomsawyer.html
images/03/afroman.html
images/03/afromario.html
pics/afterburner.html
pics2/afterburner2.html
images/03/ai.html
images/03/aigiina.html
images/nes/01/airfortress.html
images/03/air.html
images/03/airk.html
images/nes/01/airwolf.html
images/03/airwolfe.html
images/03/airwolfj.html
images/03/akagawa.html
images/nes/01/akira.html
images/03/akka.html
images/03/akuma.html
pics2/adensetsu.html
pics2/adracula.html
images/nes/01/akumajo.html
pics2/aspecial.html
pics/alunser.html
images/nes/01/alfred.html
images/03/alice.html
images/nes/01/alien3.html
images/nes/01/asyndrome.html
images/03/alien.html
images/03/all.html
images/nes/01/allpro.html
images/nes/01/allstarsoftball.html
images/nes/01/alphamission.html
pics2/altered.html
```